# EV_CLEAR flag confusion. What state of an event does it change?

Tags: c, freebsd, kqueue

My manual on `kqueue` says:

> EV_CLEAR     After the event is retrieved by the user, its state is
> reset.  This is useful for filters which report state
> transitions instead of the current state.  Note that some
> filters may automatically set this flag internally.

I did a small program that sets a timer with `EV_DISPATCH` and after first wake-up, enables it.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/event.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <yma/yreport.h>

void ykq_kev_pev(struct kevent *ev);

int main()
{
 int           status; 
 struct kevent kev;
 int           kq;

 if((kq = kqueue()) < 0){
  fprintf(stderr, " * kqueue() failed\n errno = %d\n", errno);
  return 1;
 }

 kev.ident  = 1;
 kev.filter = EVFILT_TIMER;
 kev.flags  = EV_ADD | EV_DISPATCH;
 kev.data   = 4;
 kev.fflags = NOTE_SECONDS;

l_reg_ev:
 status = kevent(kq, &kev, 1, NULL, 0, NULL);
 if(status < 0){
  fprintf(stderr, " * kevent() failed\n errno = %d\n", errno);
  return 1;
 }

 for(;;){
  
  status = kevent(kq, NULL, 0, &kev, 1, NULL);
  if(status < 0){
   fprintf(stderr, " * kevent() failed\n errno = %d\n", errno);
   return 1;
  }else if(status > 0){
   if(kev.flags & EV_ERROR){
    ykq_kev_pev(&kev);
    return 1;
   }
   ykq_kev_pev(&kev);
   kev.flags = EV_ENABLE;
   goto l_reg_ev;
  }
 }

 return 0;
}

void ykq_kev_pev(struct kevent *ev)
{
 u_short flags  = ev->flags;
 u_int   fflags = ev->fflags;
 short   filter = ev->filter;
 int64_t data   = ev->data;

 static const char *p_null = "NULL";
 static char const *vf[] = {
 "EV_ADD ",
 "EV_ENABLE ",
 "EV_DISABLE ",
 "EV_DISPATCH ",
 "EV_DELETE ",
 "EV_RECEIPT ",
 "EV_ONESHOT ",
 "EV_CLEAR ",
 "EV_EOF ",
 "EV_ERROR ",
 };
 static char const *vflt[] = {
  "EVFILT_READ",
  "EVFILT_WRITE",
  "EVFILT_EMPTY",
  "EVFILT_AIO",
  "EVFILT_VNODE",
  "EVFILT_PROC",
  "EVFILT_PROCDESC",
  "EVFILT_SIGNAL",
  "EVFILT_TIMER",
  "EVFILT_USER",
 };
 static char const *vsock_s[] = {
 "listen backlog :",
 "bytes avaible read :",
 "bytes avaible write :",
 "# times since last kevent call:",
 "# times timeout has expired since last kevent call:",
 };
 char        s_flags [255] = {0};
 const char *p_filter      = p_null;
 const char *p_data_desc   = p_null;

 /* enable, or disable */
 if(flags & EV_ENABLE){
  strcat(s_flags,vf[1]);
 }else if(flags & EV_DISABLE){
  strcat(s_flags,vf[2]);
 }

 /* possible combination of flags */
 if(flags & EV_ADD)
  strcat(s_flags,vf[0]);
 if(flags & EV_DISPATCH)
  strcat(s_flags,vf[3]);
 if(flags & EV_DELETE)
  strcat(s_flags,vf[4]);
 if(flags & EV_RECEIPT)
  strcat(s_flags,vf[5]);
 if(flags & EV_ONESHOT)
  strcat(s_flags,vf[6]);
 if(flags & EV_CLEAR)
  strcat(s_flags,vf[7]);
 if(flags & EV_EOF)
  strcat(s_flags,vf[8]);
 if(flags & EV_ERROR)
  strcat(s_flags,vf[9]);

 /* filter and fflags */
 switch(filter){
 case EVFILT_READ :    p_filter = vflt[0]; break;
 case EVFILT_WRITE:    p_filter = vflt[1]; break;
 case EVFILT_EMPTY:    p_filter = vflt[2]; break;
 case EVFILT_AIO:      p_filter = vflt[3]; break;
 case EVFILT_VNODE:    p_filter = vflt[4]; break;
 case EVFILT_PROC:     p_filter = vflt[5]; break;
 case EVFILT_PROCDESC: p_filter = vflt[6]; break;
 case EVFILT_SIGNAL:   p_filter = vflt[7]; break;
 case EVFILT_TIMER:    p_filter = vflt[8]; break;
 case EVFILT_USER:     p_filter = vflt[9]; break;
 default: break;
 }
 

 if('\0' == *s_flags){
  strcpy(s_flags, p_null);
 }

 /* signals */
 switch(filter){
 case EVFILT_SIGNAL :
  p_data_desc = vsock_s[3];
  break;
 case EVFILT_TIMER : 
  p_data_desc = vsock_s[4];
 default: break;
 }

 printf(" \t\t@ event:\n"
        "\tid      :  %lu\n",
        ev->ident        
 );
 if(*s_flags){
  printf("\tflags   :  %s\n",
         s_flags
  );
 }
 printf("\tfilter  :  %s\n"
        "\tdata    :  %s %ld\n",
        p_filter,
        p_data_desc, data
 );
 if(flags & EV_EOF){
  printf("\terror   :  %s\n",
         errnonm(fflags)
  );
 }else if((flags & EV_ERROR) && (0 != data)){
  printf("\terror   :  %s\n",
         errnonm(data)
  );
 }

}
```

The code originates from my efforts to understand `socket` programming. At some point I got confused with the state of the event flags. The above prints a *series* of:

> @ event:
> id      :  1
> flags   :  EV_DISPATCH EV_CLEAR
> filter  :  EVFILT_TIMER
> data    :  # times timeout has expired since last kevent call: 1

What is expected, is that, after first `goto`, the `EV_DISPATCH` flag will get cleared. As per manual. What exactly are those "state", that the manual talks about. More specifically, what does `EV_CLEAR` do to event, and when?

I can not understand the source code for the all procedure at its full. That is why the only thing I can do, is to wait for clarification.

P.S The OS is FreeBSD 13.1.

Comment: Nothing in the manual suggests that `EV_DISPATCH` would ever be cleared, other than re-adding the event.

Comment: @YakovGalka Thank you you for your comment. I had missed that bit of information.